# Plot with two Y axes : confidence intervals

Tags: r

I am trying to plot several points with error bars, with two y axes. 
However at every call of the plotCI or errbar functions, a new plot is initialized - with or without par(new=TRUE) calls -.

```
require(plotrix)
x <- 1:10
y1 <- x + rnorm(10)
y2<-x+rnorm(10)
delta <- runif(10)

plotCI(x,y=y1,uiw=delta,xaxt="n",gap=0)
axis(side=1,at=c(1:10),labels=rep("a",10),cex=0.7)
par(new=TRUE)
axis(4)
plotCI(x,y=y2,uiw=delta,xaxt="n",gap=0)
```

I have also tried the **twoord.plot** function from **plotrix**, but I don't think it's possible to add the error bars.

With **ggplot2** I have only managed to plot in two different panels with the same Y axis.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `add=TRUE`,

> If FALSE (default), create a new plot; if TRUE, add error bars to an
> existing plot.

For example the last line becomes:

```
    plotCI(x,y=y2,uiw=delta,xaxt="n",gap=0,add=TRUE)
```

[image: screenshot 1]

PS: hard to do this with `ggplot2`. take a look at [this hadley code](http://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2)

**EDIT**

The user coordinate system is now redefined by specifying a new user setting. Here I do it manually.

```
plotCI(x,y=y1,uiw=delta,xaxt="n",gap=0)
axis(side=1,at=c(1:10),labels=rep("a",10),cex=0.7)
usr <- par("usr")
par(usr=c(usr[1:2], -1, 20))
plotCI(x,y=y2,uiw=delta,xaxt="n",gap=0,add=TRUE,col='red')
axis(4,col.ticks ='red')
```

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: @agstudy- however the function still does not "respond" to new ylim or ylab parameters for the second plotCI call..this is extremely weird...

Comment: @agatha You can see my edit:I redefine the `usr` parameter. You can get better results using `lattice` package.

Comment: Excellent..I will have a look at that.