# R plot. Celsius on y axis with exact Fahrenheit conversion of the y labels on second y axis

Tags: r, plot

I have a plot with Celsius on y axis:

```
plot(y=0:100,x=0:100, main="temperature",xlab="time",ylab="Celsius",type="l")
```

How can I plot an identical secondary Y scale, but with the units that are shown in  Celsius  on the y axis as Fahrenheit on second y axis.
T(°F) = T(°C) × 9/5 + 32
I need the label positions of the two y axis to correspond exactly so that the secondary y label shows the converted value that is on the primary y label.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note: we don't use centigrade anymore, but Celsius.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375505/r-creating-graphs-with-two-y-axes

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I plot with 2 different y-axes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142944/how-can-i-plot-with-2-different-y-axes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In it's roughest form you can use `axis()`:

```
plot(y=0:100,x=0:100, main="temperature",xlab="time",ylab="Centigrate",type="l")

axis(4, at=0:100, labels=0:100 * 9/5 + 32)
```

You can get fewer labels by using `seq(0, 100, by=10)`. You'll also want to set `par(mar=)` to fit your axis label.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example with pretty ticks on left and right sides.

```
set.seed(1)
temp <- rnorm(10) * 10 + 10  # random temperatures

par(mar=c(5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1))  # extra margin space
plot(temp, ylab="degrees C")
ylim <- par("yaxp")[1:2]  # get range of original y-axis

# slope and offset coefficients to convert between degrees C and F
slope <- 9/5
offset <- 32
alt.ax <- pretty(slope * ylim + offset)
alt.at <- (alt.ax - offset) / slope

axis(side=4, at=alt.at, labels=alt.ax, srt=90)
mtext("degrees F", side=4, line=par("mgp")[1])
```

[image: output]