# how to connect means with line in two way CI plot..?

Tags: r

how to connect  means with line in the above two way CI plot..?? for below 
 link example.

[Plot with two Y axes : confidence intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039886/plot-with-two-y-axes-confidence-intervals)

Comment: Including a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful. Do you have any code that you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lines` in base R to plot the lines. It doesn't restart the plot.

```
library(plotrix)

set.seed(1234)    # In the linked to question 
                  # the rsults were not reproducible

x <- 1:10
y1 <- x + rnorm(10)
y2<-x+rnorm(10)
delta <- runif(10)

plotCI(x,y=y1,uiw=delta,xaxt="n",gap=0)
axis(side=1,at=c(1:10),labels=rep("a",10),cex=0.7)
lines(x, y = y1 + delta, lty = "dotted")
lines(x, y = y1 - delta, lty = "dotted")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer..it helps me a lot...Rui Barradas :)